# Can you use Storyboard without UINavigationBar?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, storyboard

As the title says, I am wondering if/how you use Storyboard without UINavigationBars? How do you disable these UINavigationBars if you just want to make use of storyboard but not this other control it comes with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view controllers will only have navigation bars provided if they're part of a `UINavigationController` stack. You're not obligated to use `UINavigationController`.

Comment: But then I cannot use Pushes, yet Modal still works. Why is that?

Comment: The methods for presenting a modal view controller are declared in `UIViewController`. The methods to push and pop a stack are implemented by `UINavigationController`, which is itself a subclass of `UIViewController`. If you need the pushing and popping of a navigation controller, you should know that `UINavigationController` also implements `-setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` which allows you to hide or show the navigation bar as needed.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I appreciate it. One last question: Is there any other way to present a different view on the screen with storyboards, or is it just limited to Push/Pop/Modal?